# Calling jquery plugin functions on JS callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've searched for an answer to this question but haven't had any success.
I am using the [audio.js](http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/) plugin for audio playback and usually stream files with:

```
// within index.html.erb
audio.load($('.track_info a', clicked_node).attr('data-src'));
audio.play();
```

When placed in a script block on any html page, it works perfectly. The problem I'm having involved attempting to call the audio plugin through a js callback. Nothing happens when I do the following:

```
// callback.js.erb
audio.load('<%= "#{@song.sample_url}" %>');
audio.play();
```

Even when I wrap that with:

```
$.getScript('/javascripts/audio.js', function(){
    alert("Successfully loaded audio.");
)};
```

Any ideas?

p.s. - The other jquery within callback.js.erb work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.getScript('/javascripts/audio.js', function(){
    audio.load('<%= @song.sample_url %>');
    audio.play();
)};
```

Comment: After trying that, and several other work around attempts, it ended up being a problem with the audio.js plugin. It's really finicky, simply taking the initialization out of a $(document).ready resolved the issue for now.. haha, I'm sure that's not best practice though! Thanks for the help ;)